# Is this much difference between orthographic and perspective normal?

Tags: modeling, orthographic

They look completely different. I know that the orthographic projection is done without the vanishing point but is it supposed to be this big of a difference. It's kind of less effective   using image reference for the face.

Demo:
[image]

Is this normal, or did I ruined my setting without knowing?

Comment: In my opinion you should work in orthographic view, you can also change the lens focal of the 3D view in the N panel if you want a perspective that deforms less

Comment: Orthographic will always look weird in your brain because human eye is not used to it. It is big difference and I dont think it's not very useful but also using perspective is not posible as way very good. I think you should change lens of orthographic view and try to make it as less deformed as possible... It's hard to make human face from reference